# How would I sort a list from a CSV file in ascending order?

Tags: python, sorting, csv

```
with open('classroom1.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in readCSV:
        name = row[0]
        scores = [int(c) for c in row[1:]]
        total = sum(scores)
```

This is my code so far and I would like to sort it in ascending order. I know that `reverse=True` will help me however I don't know how to use it here.

I have tried:

```
srt = sorted(total, key=lambda x : x[1], reverse=True)
    print(name,srt)
```

but it doesn't work.

My list is `[userName, score1, score2, score3]`, e.g. `[James, 5, 8, 4]`

Comment: It would help if we knew what your list looked like and what it should look like.

Comment: So you want  `['James',5,4,8]` --> `['James',4,5,8]`?

Comment: @Stidgeon Sorted on the sum of the scores.

Comment: this is hopeless without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You have many variables in each line, `name`, `score1`...etc. Based on which you want the sort to ascending?

Comment: Please do not deface your question. If you want to remove your question, flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to sort in ascending order, you shouldn't call `reverse=True`

if: `classroom1.csv`:

```
Ali,100,100
Bob,50,100
```

and main.py is:

```
data=[]
with open('classroom1.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in readCSV:
        name = row[0]
        scores = [int(c) for c in row[1:]]
        total=sum(scores)
        data.append((name,total))
srt=sorted(data, key=lambda x : x[1])
print srt
```

you will receive:

```
[('Bob',150),('Ali',200)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Program to short by userName with high score:
Here  is my cvs file data:

userName, score1,score2,score3
James, 7,3,8
Bob, 9,5,7
Yogi, 10,4,5

import csv
output = {}
first = True
f=open("D:\work\classroom1.cvs")
for row in csv.reader(f):
    if first:
        first = False
        continue
    key = row[0]
    row.pop(0)
    val = list(set(map(int, row)))[0]
    output[key] = val

for key in sorted(output):
    print ("%s, %s" % (key, output[key]))


Output:
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Bob, 9
James, 8
Yogi, 10
```

### >>>

```
Program to short by high score:
Here  is my cvs file data:

userName, score1,score2,score3
James, 7,3,8
Bob, 9,5,7
Yogi, 10,4,5
Abhi, 1,2,3

import csv
import operator
output = {}
first = True
f=open("D:\work\classroom1.cvs")
for row in csv.reader(f):
    if first:
        first = False
        continue
    key = row[0]
    row.pop(0)
    val = list(set(map(int, row)))[0]
    output[key] = val

sorted_output = sorted(output.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
for key,val in sorted_output:
    print ("%s, %s" % (key, val))


Output:
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Abhi, 1
Bob, 9
Yogi, 9
James, 10
>>>
```

Comment: I tried this code, however nothing I had no outputs. I changed one line of the code to f=open('classroom1.cvs',"a+") because I kept getting an error